# StatusBar based Orientation detection misses

Tags: ios, ios5

I hooked up to the orientation change notifications. I noticed that for a 90 degrees iPad turn from portrait to landscape I may get as many as 3 notifications. The last of them isn't always correct, causing me to think i'm in portrait when i'm really straight and level landscape.

I am using the notification as an excuse to get the orientation in real time. perhaps I shouldn't do it, but this is what I'm doing now:

```
 UIInterfaceOrientation interfaceOrientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;
```

Am I doing something wrong? obviously I am, question is what...

Comment: IOS never really could give solid orientation messages (of course, compared to android or WP7, it's almost godlike).  There is a UIViewController method designed specifically for orientation changes -willRotateToInterfaceOrientation which is always my litmus test though.

Comment: actually. that did it. willRotateToInterfaceOrientation. if you post this as an answer I'll be able to give you credit for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned before, the only consistent orientation message is `-willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:`.